# do search in DAT file using c

Tags: c, hexdump

Each record takes 32 bytes and conforms to this struct on x86-64 (in records.h):

```
typedef struct record {
  unsigned suncents;       // 4 bytes on x86-64
  unsigned char name_len;  // length of name
  char name[27];           // name; NOT nul-terminated! use name_len above
} record;
```

The data file is 0 or more records consecutively, and not sorted in any particular order. The provided sample.dat has 3 records. A good way to display it is hexdump -C sample.dat:

```
$ hexdump -C sample.dat 
00000000  86 07 00 00 0e 44 65 6e  6e 69 73 20 52 69 74 63  |.....Dennis Ritc|
00000010  68 69 65 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  |hie-------------|
00000020  22 01 00 00 0a 41 72 63  68 69 6d 65 64 65 73 2d  |"....Archimedes-|
00000030  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  |----------------|
00000040  00 28 6b ee 0b 41 6c 61  6e 20 54 75 72 69 6e 67  |.(k..Alan Turing|
00000050  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  |----------------|
00000060
```

Leftmost column: file position (hexadecimal). Middle chunk: bytes in hexadecimal. Right column: bytes as characters, so whenever there should be a string, you can read it. It’s 16 bytes per line, nicely two lines (32 bytes) per record.

So the question is how can I search whether there is a certain name in the file that I was given

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what prevents you from doing what you want? One general approach would be to read in the data and then use a simple loop to check the characters in `name`. Have you tried anything like that and what specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: is it like normally doing a search in a file

Comment: What does "normally" mean to you?

Comment: So is that mean it basically the same as performing a search in text files

Comment: since the file combines hexadecimal bytes and characters bytes

Comment: Actually, I want to get 4 bytes provided on x86-64 through searching the names provided

Comment: Your statement _"the file combines hexadecimal bytes and character bytes"_ demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of what a _byte_ is. All you need to do is start reading the file _opened in binary mode_. You can simply allocate a buffer of 32 bytes and read one record at a time. Copy values from the appropriate location in the record. Note that if you want to read directly into the struct you can, but you should ensure your types are actually correct (`unsigned int` has no standard-defined width) and that the compiler has not padded any elements of the struct.

Comment: `4 bytes provided on x86-64 through searching the names provided` which 4 bytes? That doesn't make any sense. Just loop through the records and compare

Comment: get the 4 bytes at very head of each record

Comment: As long as you are doing exact matches only, the `strncmp()` function is likely to be useful, but you need to be careful.  If the name being searched for is "Catherine", then you need to ensure that an entry containing "Catherine Lu" does not match.  The 'not null terminated' part also makes it tricky.  You show `'\x2D` as the fill character.  Approximate matching is still more fraught.